# Multiple timed threads in python

Tags: python, multithreading, datetime, timestamp

I have a list of timestamps that represents events at various times in the future. I run the function every 2 minutes as the source list of `times` changes regularly.

For each unique time event, I want a function to run at 2 intervals prior to the event. There are 2 issues.

One is I don’t know how to allow for however many events I’ve got in my list as some may overlap with a function supposed to run while another is sleeping (is pooling an option here?)

Two is I don’t know how to kill the current sleeps and refresh every two minutes. The `Timer` is not overriding the `time.sleep` currently.

Any solutions or alternative options appreciated. I looked at `sched` but threading seems to be the preferred route according to their documentation.

```
import datetime,time, threading

t1 = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(minutes=60)
t2 = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(minutes=62)
t3 = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
t4 = datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(days=1)

interval_minutes_before_event = [59,20]
times = [t1,t2,t3,t4]

def refresh_every_2_mins(timeslist, intervals):
    threading.Timer(120,refresh_every_2_mins)
    for event in set(timeslist):
        for interval_prior in intervals:
            print 'Sleeping for',((event - datetime.timedelta(minutes=interval_prior)) - datetime.datetime.now()).seconds, 'seconds'
            time.sleep(((event - datetime.timedelta(minutes=interval_prior)) - datetime.datetime.now()).seconds)
            # do something 
    print 'Two mins up, starting again'


refresh_every_2_mins(times,interval_minutes_before_event)
```

Comment: Can you clarify "For each unique time event, I want a function to run at 2 intervals prior to the event"

Comment: Also please clarify "This list is updated every 2 mins these events "

Comment: @theannouncer 1st: 2 times at x & y minutes before the events I want the `#do something` to happen. The x & y are in `interval_minutes_before_event`. 2nd: I changed the grammar to make this clearer. That's accomplished by the `refresh_every_2_mins function`